# Art Deco style border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm looking to achieve this border effect using pure CSS:

[image: Art Deco Border Style]

My preference would be to achieve it without adding extra div elements. Any suggestions would be appreciated

EDIT: Fixed image description

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it like below:

```css
.box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 15px solid transparent; /* control the offset of the lines */
  outline: 2px solid #000; /* adjust the 2px here */
  outline-offset: -10px; /* control the offset of the rectangle */
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at 2px 2px,#0000 25%,#000 0)
     0 0/calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px) padding-box border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

With CSS variables to easily control:

```css
.box {
  --c:red;   /* color */
  --b:2px;   /* thickness of lines */
  --o1:15px; /* offest of lines*/
  --o2:10px; /* offset of rectangle */
  
  width: 150px;
  height: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  border: var(--o1) solid transparent; 
  outline: var(--b) solid var(--c); 
  outline-offset: calc(-1*var(--o2));
  background:
    conic-gradient(from 90deg at var(--b) var(--b),#0000 25%,var(--c) 0)
     0 0/calc(100% - var(--b)) calc(100% - var(--b)) padding-box border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:green;--b:1px;--o1:20px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:blue;--b:4px;--o1:40px;--o2:20px;"></div>
<div class="box" style="--c:#000;--b:1px;--o1:10px;--o2:0;"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

.artdeco {
   position: relative;
   margin:20px;
   padding:20px;
   border:2px solid black;
   min-height:300px;
}

.artdeco:before {
   content:'';
   position: absolute;
   top:-20px;
   bottom:-20px;
   left:10px;
   right:10px;
   border-left: 2px solid black;
   border-right: 2px solid black;
}

.artdeco:after {
   content:'';
   position: absolute;
   top:10px;
   bottom:10px;
   left:-20px;
   right:-20px;
   border-top: 2px solid black;
   border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="artdeco"></div>
```

Use psuedoelements to add further rectangles to which the extra borders can be applied.