# Art deco style border - but only in some directions

Tags: css

I've stumbled upon this answer [Art Deco style border in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65758024/art-deco-style-border-in-css)
which is almost perfect for what i want to achieve - the problem is, i want to be able to use this on sections of a website that only have borders in 1 2 or 3 directions, and outline only works in an all or nothing setting.
I tried playing around with box-shadow, but i can't seem to figure out how to achieve the same result as in that question.

Can it be done?

Comment: That same question has an answer that doesn't use outline, but positioned pseudo elements.

Comment: I didn't have time to test till now, it does indeed work as i need. I stupidly didn't check the other answer - Thank you for pointing it out!